# Get app access token for app user

Tags: java, facebook, access-token, facebook4j

I have created a facebook app. I have my own access token and its working. My aim is to generate a app access token for the users who are going to use my app. User will provide their credentials and appId,appSecret and should get the access token.

My aim is that user should not have to go to developer site. He will just run the app.

Comment: Here's how you generate an app access token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens